# Flask-admin: Is it possible to apply filters (which can be disable) to a view/endpoint by default

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I would like to know how to get a filter applied by default when I access a page.

I want this filter to be able to be disabled.

Some sample code below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

from . import models
from . import views
db.create_all()
admin = Admin(app,
              name='Interface',
              base_template='my_master.html',
              template_mode='bootstrap3',
              url='/')
admin.add_view(views.MyView(models.User, db.session, endpoint='users', url='/users'))

# models
from . import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'USER'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    label = db.Column(db.String()) # 2 possible values: True abd False

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

# views
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import BaseSQLAFilter

class FilterLabels(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        if value =='0':
            return query.filter(self.column == 'True')
        if value =='1':
            return query.filter(self.column == 'False')
    def operation(self):
        return u'equals'

    def get_options(self, view):
        return [(0, 'True'), (1, 'False')]

class MyView(ModelView):

    column_list = ('id', 'name', 'label')
    column_searchable_list = column_list 
    column_filters = ['id', 'name', FilterLabels]

    def get_url(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return url_for(endpoint, **kwargs) # Should I add something here?

    def is_accessible(self):
        return True
```

'''

What I want?
[image]

When I acces the page, I want the filter to be applied (FilterLabels).
I want this filter to be easily disable

Can you help me?

Comment: *column_default_sort* is a good start, but I don't know how to disable it through the UI

Comment: "When I access the page for the first time" - what are you considering as "first time" ?

Comment: When you access the url with Get method, like typing "www.google.com" to search something

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your get_query and get_count_query function in your ModelView class.

here is an example

http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/post/publish : will filter my model post with status equal to publish.

```
class PostPublishView(ModelView):
    def is_visible(self):
        return False

    def get_query(self):
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.status=='publish')

    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.status=='publish')

admin.add_view(PostPublishView(Post, db.session, name="Publish", endpoint='/post/publish'))
```

or you can @expose a link

http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/post/showpublish

```
class PostView(ModelView):
     
    @expose("/post/showpublish")
    def showpublish(self):
        return super().index_view()


    def get_query(self):
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(self.model.status=='publish')

    def get_count_query(self):
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(self.model.status=='publish')

admin.add_view(PostView(Post, db.session))
```